# Why the java.net.HttpURLConnection become sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java

I have a code like this:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) loginUrl.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
connection.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://www.icourse163.org/member/logout.htm");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connection.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
```

I the connection is a instance of HttpURLConnection, But when I **debug** the code. When the code runs to  `OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();`.I saw that the `getOutputStream()` is the  `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection`'s method. why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `java.net.HttpURLConnection` is an abstract class, and `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection` is its implementation in the Oracle JRE.